# Hiding menu on specific pages

Tags: menus

I am having issue with hiding top menu on certain pages. Here are the sites I was trying to hide menu https://domain.com/cookies-statement/ https://domain.com/privacy-policy/ it seems, solutions from other threads, doesnt work for me (or I am doing something wrong) please tell me if this even possible to do it with my theme Thank you

Comment: You need to make things easy for people to help you, what theme are you using, what have you tried, what code do you use etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the page id'd and the class of top menu wrapper those specific pages where you want to hide the and the class of top menu wrapper, as follows :
.page-id-99 .top-menu-wrapper {
display : none;
}

Please change the 99 to the page id and top menu class according to your theme respectively